# React Native MapBox is not following the blue dot on iOS

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm trying to get MapBox follow the user (blue dot) but it is not following, the dot moves but the camera stays still.

Also tried with Mapbox.UserTrackingModes.Follow

The same code works with Android.

```
     <Mapbox.MapView
        ref={map => { this.map = map; }}

        styleURL={Mapbox.StyleURL.Light}
        zoomLevel={15}
        centerCoordinate={this.initCenterLocation()}
        onRegionIsChangin={this.updateGeoFire()}
        style={{flex: 1}}
        showUserLocation={true}
        userTrackingMode={Mapbox.UserTrackingModes.FollowWithHeading}
      >
```

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have to re-center the map  so that it follow the dot

```
recenter() {
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    userTrackingMode: Mapbox.userTrackingMode.followWithHeading
                });
            }, 500);
        }
    }
```

similar to this